# corona same physics motion on different screen resolution

Tags: physics, resolution, coronasdk, game-physics

I'm developing a game, as a tutorial, learning experience

Specs summary:

- imagine something like icehockey, but with static obstacles on the field ( thumbtacks ).
- turn based, each players shoots by dragging ball and applying linear impulse on opposite direction
- all of this is MULTI-PLAYER

Basically, after you shoot, you tell the other player's app that it must apply "this" force to the ball. Considering it's the same engine, I imagined I would get the same result on both devices, therefore the only communication will envolve sending the force params when the time is right. This is correct AS LONG AS THEY HAVE THE SAME RESOLUTION. If I shoot a straight line, no obstacles, then everything seems fine ( I can't really see if there's a very small offset ), but with obstacles, collision etc. the motion is not the same ( not the same trajectory ) on different resolutions ( devices )

I need to know if there is some way I can make this work the same on all devices. I need to find a way so I can replicate in minute detail a movement ( complex, not straight line ) on different screen/resolution.

Some technical details:

- I'm using the letterbox scale
- 1200w 800h resolution ( don't really know why I chose this :) ... it seems really dumb now ... but you get the picture, I'm using basically a resolution bigger than most of the devices I test on )
- physics.setScale( 100 ) = this seemed important on some point.

PS: This is meant to be a tutorial; I'm aware that I can send the trajectory lines then compose the movement OR find another way to replicate the motion, but I need to understand EXACTLY this issue, since I'll have to confront it in future games.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works but you can try this:

```
( forceVariable / 1200 ) * display.contentWidth
```

( Assuming, your width is still 1200 px

It worked with images for me

Comment: not really. The problem isn't the force, corona does a good job translating it to "real life" coordinates. But still, maybe some decimals got lost on the way, float is not that accurate and we're talking about dead center accuracy here